# Tkinter window or pop up not opening

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

```
from tkinter import*
 
class LibraryManagementSystem:
    def __init__(self,root):
        self.root=root
        self.root.title("Library Management System")
        self.root.geometry("1550x800+0+0")



        lbltitle=Label(self.root,text="Library Management System",bg="brown",fg="black",bd=14,relief=RIDGE,padx=2,pady=6)
        lbltitle.pack(side=TOP,fill=X)




        if __name__ == "__main__":
            root=Tk()
            obj=LibraryManagementSystem(root)
            root.mainloop()
```

I am new to coding and trying to run this code in vs code. And I am following a tutorial for this but the person who's teaching runs the code and a popup window shows but mine doesn't. Is there anything wrong with the code?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please ensure that your script has the proper indents.  the ```if __name__ == "__main__":``` block should be flushed with the left margin.  Otherwise, you're not running anything.

Comment: Thankyou @ewokx ,it worked

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Frist you need to check the Python version and Tkinter version
and it's correctly installed on the system

Please try this

```html
from tkinter import Tk, Label, RIDGE, X

class LibraryManagementSystem:
    def __init__(self, root):
        self.root = root
        self.create_gui()

    def create_gui(self):
        lbltitle = Label(self.root, text="Library Management System", bg="brown", fg="black", bd=14, relief=RIDGE, padx=2, pady=6)
        lbltitle.pack(side=TOP, fill=X)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = Tk()
    obj = LibraryManagementSystem(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

also refer official document of the Tkinter
https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.html